# UNIQUE inside CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

This question is new twist of [An IF inside a check constraint SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617743/an-if-inside-a-check-constraint-sql). I want to do something similar to the following check (which throws an `ORA-00936: missing expression` exception):

```
ALTER TABLE t_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_unique_active CHECK
    ( 
        ( tb_active = 0 ) OR  
        ( tb_active = -1 AND UNIQUE(tb_active, tb_img, tb_objid)) 
    );
```

The objetive is to be sure (at DBMS level) that only one row with the same objid is active although inactive rows can be duplicated (an historical view of the rows).

It can be done in a trigger but it seems to be better using the *check* as explained in [UNIQUE constraint vs checking before INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889843/unique-constraint-vs-checking-before-insert) question.

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this with a `unique` index:

```
create unique index unq_table_active 
    on ( (case when tb_active = -1 then tb_img end),
         (case when tb_active = -1 then tb_objid end)
       )
```

Oracle allows multiple rows with `NULL` values in a unique index.